# Mongodb: Find in another collection, if data not found in first collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want to find data from either of 2 collections. If the data is not found in first, it must look into the second collection.

I tried to use $lookup with aggregation pipeline, but somehow, it won't work in the present case.

**I am using Mongoose here (version 4.10.8)**

I have *DestinationPage* as one collection, where I find a document matching with *destinationPage_name*, if I don't get the data (will return null, if so) then I wish to find it in *SpecialityPage* collection matching with *specialityPage_name*.

```
 DestinationPage.aggregate([
        { "$match" : { "destinationPage_name": { $regex: SEARCH_REF_DESTINATION, $options: 'i' } }},
        { "$lookup" : {
            "from" : "SpecialityPage",
            "localField" : "specialityPage_name",
            "foreignField" : { $regex: SEARCH_REF_DESTINATION, $options: 'i' },
            "as" : "data2"
          }
        },

      ]).then(doc => {
        console.log('document', doc);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error("got error : ", err);
      })
```

The above code gives error as,

```
"The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument"
```

If I add `{ cursor:{} }` to it, I don't see even console printing.

***OPTION:***
I can check data in one collection, then if I don't get any data, then in callback, I can check another collection. However I don't consider it as a efficient way of doing.

Thanks.

'#stayhomestaysafe'

Answer (score 0):

Your mongoose version is not compatible with MongoDB `v4.10.8`.

You need to upgrade to the recent version `v5.9.9`

[MongoDB Server Version Compatibility](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/compatibility.html)